# Use Ansible playbook to enable mysql bin logging for incremental backups

Tags: mysql, ansible, mysqlbinlog

I have been doing this manually by uncommenting the last lines in the `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

```
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
# server-id     = 1
# log_bin           = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
# binlog_expire_logs_seconds    = 2592000
max_binlog_size   = 100M
# binlog_do_db      = include_database_name
# binlog_ignore_db  = include_database_name
```

However i would like to automate this with Ansible which am using to set up the database which i have already achieved.

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common approach and usual way is to use the [`template` module – Template a file out to a target host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html)

```
cat templates/mysqld.cnf.j2
```

```ini
# Ansible managed MySQL deamon config

max_binlog_size   = {{ binlog_size }}M
binlog_do_db      = {{ database_name }}
binlog_ignore_db  = {{ database_name }}
```

and a task like

```yaml
- name: Make sure MySQL deamon 
  template:
    src: templates/mysqld.cnf.j2
    dest: /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

**Further Documenation**

- [Templating (Jinja2)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_templating.html)

Comment: Great, had thought about doing it this way too. cheers